# Clang cannot find include directory?

Tags: c++, vim, clang, syntax-checking, youcompleteme

I just moved all my header files to be in the `include` directory of my project, rather than having both .cpp and .h in the `src` directory. I'm using YouCompleteMe in vim and now when I open vim, it tells me that my header files cannot be found on the side to alert me of compiler errors. Specifically, it gives me errors on the `#include "my_header.h"` of `my_header.h file not found` and errors on each method saying `use of undeclared identifier`. However, the code compiles just fine. And the auto-completion works fine. It seems that clang cannot find where my header files are located now since I moved them `../include`. If I change my `#include` line to be `#include "../include/my_header"`, all of the errors to away. But it seems better to only have `#include "my_header.h"` in all of my `.cpp` files or `#include <my_header.h>`.

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: In your *.ycm_extra_conf.py* file add `-I../include` to the `flags` list.

Comment: @Praetorian That's it! Ah, thanks so much! That was driving me crazy.